# UICollectionView doesn't fill up page entirely, how do I stop it from pushing items to the next page when they should be on one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm trying to have a UICollectionView page horizontally, so I need it to layout vertically. However, my collection view has a different grid structure; the top row has one item in it, while the bottom row (there's two rows) has three items in it.

This structure does not seem to work well with laying out vertically. It seems that it lays out the top image first, then the first image on the bottom, then returns to the top, sees there's no more room, *and puts the next item on the next page*. For whatever reason, it will not fill up the rest of the page, even though there's vertical room remaining (two spaces left in fact), it just jumps to the next page.

Obviously this is not ideal at all. Is there a way to stop this behavior with collection views, and actually have it fill the available area?

Answer (score 1):

So your first item is as wide as the screen and next three each one third of the screen?

Seems like the third items width is not the issue as you have enough space for two more items, what about the height though? And make sure you set the following methods to 0 spacing if required (assuming there is no spacing between your items):

```
-(UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}

-(CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is correct. The height of the others are fine, as they're all the same height as the first one on the bottom row, which shows up fine. And yes those methods all return zero.

Comment: Did you figure it out? 
Try setting clipToBounds for cell and image view to YES. If it's not even that, try a collection view without the images, just background colours?

Comment: Did both, no luck. Writing a custom layout. :/

Comment: You aren't using any scroll views in your cell view or collection view, are you? You need to add self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; to your view controller if you are. Otherwise, this is just absurd.